# Consistency of addresses for Local SEO

Tags: seo, local-seo, address

I am updating all online occurrences of a companies address and in Facebook there is an auto fill that if used will allow people to find the location in Facebook Places. This address has the county name but not the region name.

Should I change everything to match this address or does having some differences not have much impact on Local SEO as long as the post code and first line of address are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about variations such as Street vs St. that is a strong differentiation as Hummingbird (August 2013) looks at synonymous relationships in context. Having both increases overall relevance for "near me" queries.

If you're talking about "123 front st, suite 700, Big Town, West Jersey" vs "123 front st, #700, Big Town, WJ, 12345" then I would try to improve consistency of these mentions.

Comment: While I agree that each site should follow standards that are clear and concise with consistency between sites being paramount, I just want to say that search engines, Google in particular, has long standing semantic algorithms that can very easily recognize NAP in any form and parse it correctly. However, it is even wiser still to use schema.org mark-up for NAP and other important data elements where ever possible. Cheers!!